# System.ArgumentException index 140

Tags: c#

Im working with a webapi and when I run it locally, I get the weird error below. There is nothing different with this setup than another webapi I've been using locally, same local sqlserver, etc. Whats really odd is, I assume `index 140` would be char 140. HOWEVER, if I modify the line, put pure garbage in it, etc., it always returns that same error with the same index. Im not sure if there's another *hidden* connectionstring somewhere?

> System.ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 140.

> at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.GetKeyValuePair(String connectionString, Int32 currentPosition, StringBuilder buffer, Boolean useOdbcRules, String& keyname, String& keyvalue)
> at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Dictionary'2 parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Dictionary'2 synonyms, Boolean firstKey)
> at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Dictionary'2 synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules)
> at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder.set_ConnectionString(String value)
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder..ctor(String connectionString)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerConnection.<>c.<get_IsMultipleActiveResultSetsEnabled>b__7_0(String cs)
> at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary'2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func'2 valueFactory)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerConnection.get_IsMultipleActiveResultSetsEnabled()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Query.Internal.SqlServerCompiledQueryCacheKeyGenerator.GenerateCacheKey(Expression query, Boolean async)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression query)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable'1.GetEnumerator()
> at System.Collections.Generic.List'1..ctor(IEnumerable'1 collection)
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable'1 source)
> at MBRAPI.Services.Appointments_Service.GetAllAppointments(Appointments_JsonWrapper rawJson) in C:\Users\farm\source\repos\MBRAPI\Services\Appointments_Service.cs:line 170
> at MBRAPI.Controllers.Appointments_Controller.Appointments_GetAll(Appointments_JsonWrapper rawJson) in C:\Users\farm\source\repos\MBRAPI\Controllers\Appointments_Controller.cs:line 29
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(ActionContext actionContext, IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask'1 actionResultValueTask)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)

This is my relevant program.cs:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("MBRContextConnection");

    builder.Services.AddDbContext<MBRContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

    builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true).AddEntityFrameworkStores<MBRContext>();

    // Add services to the container.

    builder.Services.AddControllers();
    builder.Services.AddScoped<IAppointments, Appointments_Service>();
    builder.Services.AddScoped<IDog, Dog_Service>();
    builder.Services.AddScoped<IFoster, Foster_Service>();

    builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
    builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

    var app = builder.Build();

    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.MapControllers();

    app.Run();
```

This is my local appsettings.json:

```
    {
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MBRContextConnection": "Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=MBR;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False;"
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure, but my guess is that if you've been changing the connection string and keep getting an error at the same index, your program may be using another connection string somewhere. do you have a config file or anything else where a connection string might be stored?

Comment: @RufusL is there a chance that this being a project within a larger solution, that its somehow taking a string from another project?

Comment: I would search the whole solution for connection strings and see if anything stands out.

Comment: How's the connection string being consumed?

Comment: @beautifulcoder its being consumed in the program.cs of this particular project

Comment: @RufusL can you answer the question, your comment got the wheels spinning to the solution.After unloading all the other projects in the solution, I was getting the same results. So I went through and re-named the connectionString and it started working properly. I still have not found anywhere where there was an identical connectionString setup.